# Converting BufferedImage to OpenCv Mat

Tags: java, opencv, bufferedimage

I'm trying to convert a BufferedImage to a Mat, used in OpenCV.

The code I found for this ( on many different sites, including stackoverflow ) is:

```
public Mat bufferedImageToMat(BufferedImage bi) {
      Mat mat = new Mat(bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
      byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
      mat.put(0, 0, data);
      return mat;
    }
```

Eclipse gives me the following error:

DataBufferType cannot be resolved to a type.

I have imported java.awt.image.BufferedImage; so this cant be the problem.

Any ideas? 
Or maybe another way to do this conversion?

Comment: BufferedImages have a type. Check if it is `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` or if it has another type...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with

```
public Mat bufferedImageToMat(BufferedImage bi) {
    Mat mat = new Mat(bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth(), CV_8UC(3));

    int r, g, b;
    UByteRawIndexer indexer = mat.createIndexer();
    for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
            int rgb = bi.getRGB(x, y);

            r = (byte) ((rgb >> 0) & 0xFF);
            g = (byte) ((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF);
            b = (byte) ((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF);

            indexer.put(y, x, 0, r);
            indexer.put(y, x, 1, g);
            indexer.put(y, x, 2, b);
        }
    }
    indexer.release();
    return mat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about performance you can try this:

```java
    public static Mat toMat(RenderedImage image) {
        File temp = null;
        try {
            temp = File.createTempFile(Images.PREFIX, Images.SUFFIX);
            ImageIO.write(image, Images.PNG, temp);
            Mat result = Imgcodecs.imread(temp.getAbsolutePath());
            Files.delete(temp.toPath());
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //you can change this exception to whatever.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
```